# Upgrading to Sitecore 9.3 but StringUtil.GetSizeString is missing. What do I use instead?

Tags: upgrade

This question came from [@AlphonseAmala on Twitter](https://twitter.com/AlphonseAmala/status/1268200043611336705):

> @Sitecore need replacement function for StringUtil.GetSizeString(long
>   size) - it's not available in Sitecore.Kernel version 14 (Sitecore 9.3
>   migration) issue. Need help

When upgrading to Sitecore Experience Platform 9.3, what change should be made to replace GetSizeString(long size)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Sitecore Experience Platform 9.2 release, the Sitecore.StringUtil.GetSizeString(long) method was marked as [Obsolete]. It was removed in version 9.3.

When building against 9.2, the Obsolete error message displayed reads:

> Please use 'MainUtil.FormatSize(size, translate: false)' API instead.

This utility method is also found in the same namespace and DLL (Sitecore.Kernel).

When upgrading to Sitecore XP 9.3, replace your calls to StringUtil.GetSizeString(long size) with MainUtil.FormatSize(long size,bool translate).